# what can I use to profile C++ module code for android

Tags: android, c++, performance

Can anyone suggest some good performance profiling tool for C/C++ code
that does not require recompiling/linking. I need for android platform.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the NDK tools , does it have some profiler with it

Comment: Check out the [android-ndk-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/) project. If you look at their wiki they've got some examples of how to use it.

Comment: Can you profile your code in desktop? Because valgrind is amazing

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while i was not able to find descent one, so i solved this issue  i.e. by taking timestamp as i enter a function and as i leave a function use them to find out time spent in function, it took little effort but i was able to find out the portion which is casuing bottleneck, you can give it a try. Not as good as something already cooked but it may help you identify problems!

Answer (score 0):

I have found one: ARM DS-5 Community Edition (http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/). It seems that this tool meets my requirement.